# ltspice, unrecognized option rshunt

Tags: ltspice

I'm using LTSPice XVII.
I'm trying to set a resistor to every node, helping convergence.

This is not recognized (spell?)

```
.options rshunt = 1e12
```

however, capacitor is working

```
.options cshunt = 1e-13
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: don't you mean gshunt?

Comment: well... with gshunt=1E16 the circuit stay at zero voltage. I have a opamp so probably will hurt internally :)

Comment: but I think you're right, thank you!

Comment: Hmm my update never upgraded it to XVII, thanks for giving me the version info :)

Comment: I know LTspice's help is not very user friendly, even if it does convey the message, but sometimes I find it very difficult to not downvote for the sheer lazyness. In this case, it was as simple as finding `LTspice > Dot command > .option`. Didn't downvote, but it sure didn't deserve the +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 1e-16. It appears that gshunt is a conductance value and not a resistance value. I later found I did not need the parameter as I had mistakes in my schematic where I an inductor connected to the wrong point and I didn't have them coupled as a transformer.